# Laravel echo pusher not receiving broadcast events

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, vue.js, pusher

I've a problem that I'm trying to fix all day now. I've followed
[this](https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-a-laravel-chat-app-with-pusher/) tutorial. The goal is to make a chat with `Laravel echo`, `vue.js` and `pusher`.

I've done everything exactly like the tutorial but for some reason I do not receive any events in my [pusher](https://pusher.com/) console. Only the connection shows up:[image]

But no events. The event that I fire looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Message;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $message;

    /**
     * MessageSent constructor.
     * @param User $user
     * @param Message $message
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, Message $message)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat');
    }
}
```

I fire the event like this:

```
broadcast(new MessageSent($user, $message))->toOthers();
```

When I `dd('test');` like this in my MessageSent event class:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{

    dd('test');

    return new PrivateChannel('chat');
}
```

The `dd('test');` shows up in my network tab.

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and `Vue.js 2.0` with `Homestead`. What could be going on here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks likes you are following [this](https://jplhomer.org/2017/01/building-realtime-chat-app-laravel-5-4-vuejs/) tutorial. I also had a hard time to figure it out. I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754318/laravel-5-4-event-broadcasting-not-work-with-vuejs/42938307#42938307). Can you please check it out?

I worked on typing feature in the chat system. Please take a look at the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/rutvij2292/ChatApp).

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your debug console screenshot you are never managing to subscribe to any channels, have you set up the necessary authentication for the private channel subscription?

The complete demo code for the tutorial that you've been following is [on github](https://github.com/ammezie/laravel-chat) so you might want to take a look at that and see where yours differs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Laravel 5.4, make sure you have set-up the channel authentication.

For example, in your `routes/channels.php` file, there should be something like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return true; // change this to your authentication logic
});
```